# Manually Build SOAP service request

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, soap, arduino

I need to build a SOAP request for request a webservice stored on Google App Engine, because platform where i'm working doesn't have a library for manage webservice request (i'm programming an Arduino Board).
My SOAP server it's stored at

http://arduino-data-server.appspot.com/

and i need to connect to server before to send request. This is my code:

```
char server[] = "www.arduino-data-server.appspot.com"; //server address
WiFiClient client;

if(client.connect(server, 80)) {
Serial.println("Connected to server, preparing request");
client.println("POST /dataserver HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: http://arduino-data-server.appspot.com");
client.println("Content-Type: text:xml; charset=utf-8");
client.println("SOAPAction: \"http://example.com/getData\"");
client.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
client.println("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
client.println("<soap:Body>");
client.println("<sendData xmlns=\"http://example.com/\"");
client.println("<temperatura> 22 </temperatura>");
client.println("<umidita> 55 </umidita>");
client.println("</sendData>");
client.println("</soap:Body>");
client.println("</soap:Envelope>");
client.println();
Serial.println("OK");
 }else {
Serial.println("KO");
  }
}
```

everithing seems to be ok, but on my server, no incoming connections are detected. What's wrong?

here it is wsdl file: arduino-data-server.appspot.com/FunctionsService.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

I think itisn't the problem, but is missing a > symbol:

```
client.println("<sendData xmlns=\"http://example.com/\"");
```

should be:

```
client.println("<sendData xmlns=\"http://example.com/\">");
```

Regards from Argentina

PD: I'm trying to do the same as you with arduino.

Comment: The problem was that i've missing "content-lenght" body attribute of POST method. Server doesn't processing http packet if that field it's uncorrect or missing. Just generate the http body inside a separate function so you can calcululate length attribute and append it to request